# Converting flat structure to typical parent-child tree in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

For some reason I'm drawing a blank on this, maybe my brain is overloaded lately but I can't seem to get it right. I'm trying to convert a structured list of unique values into a tree structure.

I have a list of unique values that are set up in [Apache MultiKey](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/keyvalue/MultiKey.html) classes, which is basically just a wrapper for any number of objects that make up a key. They list looks like this:

```
List<MultiKey> _data = new ArrayList<MultiKey>()
```

And the data inside looks like this:

```
MultiKey[ABC]
MultiKey[ABC, 111]
MultiKey[ABC, 111, CHF]
MultiKey[ABC, 111, CHF, AT000B049432]
MultiKey[ABC, 111, CHF, CH0012814965]
MultiKey[ABC, 111, CHF, CH0018550399]
MultiKey[ABC, 111, CHF, CH0020626773]
MultiKey[ABC, 111, EUR]
MultiKey[ABC, 111, EUR, AT0000A001X2]
MultiKey[ABC, 111, EUR, AT0000A0U3T4]
MultiKey[ABC, 111, USD]
MultiKey[ABC, 111, USD, CH0002497458]
MultiKey[DEF]
MultiKey[DEF, 222]
MultiKey[DEF, 222, CHF]
MultiKey[DEF, 222, CHF, AT000B049432]
MultiKey[DEF, 222, CHF, CH0012814965]
MultiKey[DEF, 222, EUR]
MultiKey[DEF, 222, EUR, AT0000A001X2]
```

The class that makes up the Tree Node is a classic parent-child tree node that looks like this (additional methods excluded for simplicity).

```
public class DataTreeNode {

    private Object              _data;
    private DataTreeNode        _parent;
    private List<DataTreeNode>  _children;

    public DataTreeNode() {
        super();
    }

    public DataTreeNode(Object data) {
        super();
        _data = data;
    }

    public DataTreeNode getParent() {
        return _parent;
    }

    public void setParent(DataTreeNode parent) {
        _parent = parent;
    }

    public Object getData() {
        return _data;
    }

    public void addChild(DataTreeNode child) {
        if (!_children.contains(child)) {
            _children.add(child);
            child.setParent(this);
        }
    }

    public List<DataTreeNode> getChildren() {
        return _children;
    }

}
```

The idea is to loop through the keys and (using sample data) to build a tree like this:

```
ABC
  111
    CHF
      AT000B049432
      CH0012814965
      CH0018550399
      CH0020626773
    EUR
      AT0000A001X2
      AT0000A0U3T4
    USD
      CH0002497458
DEF
  222
    CHF
      AT000B049432
      CH0012814965
    EUR
      AT0000A001X2
```

Here's a fully runnable Java sample that builds the sample data using the MultiKey structure, but is missing the convert-to-tree implementation.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.collections.keyvalue.MultiKey;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String [] args) { 
        List<MultiKey> data = new ArrayList<MultiKey>();

        data.add(new MultiKey(new Object [] { "ABC" }));
        data.add(new MultiKey(new Object [] { "ABC", "111" }));
        data.add(new MultiKey(new Object [] { "ABC", "111", "CHF" }));
        data.add(new MultiKey(new Object [] { "ABC", "111", "CHF", "AT000B049432" }));
        data.add(new MultiKey(new Object [] { "ABC", "111", "CHF", "CH0012814965" }));
        data.add(new MultiKey(new Object [] { "ABC", "111", "CHF", "CH0018550399" }));
        data.add(new MultiKey(new Object [] { "ABC", "111", "CHF", "CH0020626773" }));
        data.add(new MultiKey(new Object [] { "ABC", "111", "EUR" }));
        data.add(new MultiKey(new Object [] { "ABC", "111", "EUR", "AT0000A001X2" }));
        data.add(new MultiKey(new Object [] { "ABC", "111", "EUR", "AT0000A0U3T4" }));
        data.add(new MultiKey(new Object [] { "ABC", "111", "USD" }));
        data.add(new MultiKey(new Object [] { "ABC", "111", "USD", "AT0000A0U3T4" }));
        data.add(new MultiKey(new Object [] { "DEF" }));
        data.add(new MultiKey(new Object [] { "DEF", "222" }));
        data.add(new MultiKey(new Object [] { "DEF", "222", "CHF" }));
        data.add(new MultiKey(new Object [] { "DEF", "222", "CHF", "AT000B049432" }));
        data.add(new MultiKey(new Object [] { "DEF", "222", "CHF", "CH0012814965" }));
        data.add(new MultiKey(new Object [] { "DEF", "222", "EUR" }));
        data.add(new MultiKey(new Object [] { "DEF", "222", "EUR", "AT0000A001X2" }));

        DataTreeNode treeFromData = Sample.getTreeFor(data);
        // ...
    }

    public static DataTreeNode getTreeFor(List<MultiKey> data) {
        // TODO: THIS!
        return null;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help solving this!

Comment: Is this homework or some kind of assignment?

Comment: It's not, it's a private project-related problem I've struggled with for 2 days and I'm getting stuck trying to solve it.

Comment: MultiKey is meant to be used as the key for a Map entry; whoever gave you the data in that shape did not understand it.

Comment: OK, so if this is not an assignment, please [edit] your question and include your implementation of `// TODO: THIS!`. Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

If it is not homework, you are presumably free to use any data structures that will simplify things.

I suggest using a Map to map e.g. "ABC" to the node representing it. That will make building your tree much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for people commenting, in the end my brain finally clicked. I agree MultiKey is not the ideal structure, but essentially it does the job.

I added the following methods to the DataTreeNode class:

```
public void printTree() {
    printTree(0);
}

private void printTree(int i) {
    for (int x = 0; x < i; x++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(this);
    for (DataTreeNode child : _children) {
        child.printTree(i+1);
    }
}

public void buildFrom(DataTreeNode root, MultiKey mk) {
    buildFrom(root, 0, mk);
}

private void buildFrom(DataTreeNode root, int start, MultiKey mk) {
    if (start >= mk.getKeys().length) {
        return;
    }
    // get value
    Object val = mk.getKey(start);
    // value exists?
    DataTreeNode tn = root.getChildWithValue(val);
    if (tn == null) {
        tn = new DataTreeNode(val);
        root.addChild(tn);
    }
    else {
        buildFrom(tn, ++start, mk);
    }       
}

private DataTreeNode getChildWithValue(Object o) {
    for (DataTreeNode tn : _children) {
        if (tn.getData() == o) {
            return tn;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "[DataTreeNode: " + _data + "]";
}
```

And the getTreeFor methods becomes:

public static DataTreeNode getTreeFor(List data) {
    DataTreeNode root = new DataTreeNode();

```
for (MultiKey mk : data) {
    DataTreeNode node = new DataTreeNode();
    node.buildFrom(root, mk);           
}

return root;
```

}

thus finally

```
treeFromData.printTree();
```

prints out

```
[DataTreeNode: null]
 [DataTreeNode: ABC]
  [DataTreeNode: 111]
   [DataTreeNode: CHF]
    [DataTreeNode: AT000B049432]
    [DataTreeNode: CH0012814965]
    [DataTreeNode: CH0018550399]
    [DataTreeNode: CH0020626773]
   [DataTreeNode: EUR]
    [DataTreeNode: AT0000A001X2]
    [DataTreeNode: AT0000A0U3T4]
   [DataTreeNode: USD]
    [DataTreeNode: AT0000A0U3T4]
 [DataTreeNode: DEF]
  [DataTreeNode: 222]
   [DataTreeNode: CHF]
    [DataTreeNode: AT000B049432]
    [DataTreeNode: CH0012814965]
   [DataTreeNode: EUR]
    [DataTreeNode: AT0000A001X2]
```

Apart from cleaning up the code, it works.

Thanks again!